# How to sync facebook events with my android 2.3.4 calendar?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sync, calendar, facebook

I'm trying to sync my facebook events with my android calendar. The goal is to have an automatic sync between facebook events and 'some' account that is usable by android 2.3.4 account management. I choose google account as the most known to me.

My plan was to:
1. sync facebook calendar with google calendar using 'ical' (https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178 and https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en)
2. sync the google account with my android device so I have access to the google's calendar.

Unfortunately the facebook > google sync doesn't work and I get "We could not parse the calendar at the URL requested." error message. Changing 'webcal' prefix into 'http' or 'https' doesn't help. I tried to import my facebook event into other calendar (thunderbird's lightning) and it worked without any problems. I also tried to export the calendar into ical file (.ics) and import it (from file, not from url like previously) and it worked. It displayed my facebook events in my google calendar, but as I understand this is on-time-action and this won't sync.

Some other information that might be useful:
- android 2.3.4 doesn't support google calendar app, I'm using the 'default' one
- I can't upgrade my android
- the default facebook app is too clunky and I'm using the lite version, but I can't find any calendar option there
- I'm ok with using other apps to make the sync working
- I'm not ok with daily manual sync.

Do you know how to sync facebook events with my android calendar?